Iterating over class attribute which is a list of objects
I have a following class structure for defining a pdf document from which I need to extract form values (later store it in CSV, but that is sth out of the scope of this question).

from typing import List
import fitz
from pymupdf import Document

class FormField:
    def __init__(self, form_field_name: str):

        self.form_field_name: str = form_field_name
        self.form_field_value: str | None = None
        self.form_field_type: str | None = None

class Page:
    def __init__(self, page_name: str, page_no: int):
        self.page_name: str = page_name
        self.page_no: int = page_no
        self.list_of_forms: List[FormField] = []

    def add_form_fields(self, form_fields: List[FormField]):
        for form in form_fields:
            self.list_of_forms.append(form)

class PDFDocument:
    def __init__(self, path: str):
        self.path = path
        self.number_of_pages: int
        self.list_of_pages: List[Page] = []
    
    @property
    def document_instance(self) -> Document:
        doc: Document = fitz.open(self.path)  
        self.number_of_pages = doc.page_count
        return doc
   
    def add_pages(self, pages: List[Page]):
        for page in pages:
            self.list_of_pages.append(page)

in main.py I define structure of the PDF document (which fields I am interested in extracting):
document = PDFDocument("example.pdf")
document.document_instance

first_page = Page("first page", 1)
document.add_pages([first_page])
    
field_1 = FormField("field_1")
field_2 = FormField("field_2")
first_page.add_form_fields([field_1,field_2])

What I need is a method or set of method that will now iterate with defined object of the PDF document and retrieve values and types of forms present on the document. Got first method right I think:
def search_for_form_value_and_type_in_pdf_document(self, field_name: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
        for page in self.document_instance:
            for field in page.widgets(): # method from pymupdf retrieving form items
                if field.field_name == field_name:
                    return field.field_value, field.field_type_string

I do sth wrong on apply though:
def apply_value_to_the_field(self, field: FormField, field_value: str, field_type: str):
        for page in self.list_of_pages:
            for f in page.list_of_forms:
                if f.form_field_name == field.form_field_name:
                    f.form_field_value = field_value
                    f.form_field_type = field_type

Both methods are part of PDFDocument class:
code to run them:
main.py
...
all_forms = []
for page in document.list_of_pages:
     for form in page.list_of_forms:
         all_forms.append(form)

value, type = document.search_for_form_value_and_type_in_employee_dialogue_document(
        target_achievement_score_manager.form_field_name
    )

    for form in all_forms:
        value, type = (
            document.search_for_form_value_and_type_in_employee_dialogue_document(
                form.form_field_name
            )
        )
document.apply_value_to_the_field(form, field_value=value, field_type=type)


Code above only applies change to last form object. It doesn't save/update information for all the rest. Object returned is missing types and values...

your search method only returns one value. you should store all your results and return the stored values in the end. (your main.py looks very bad, you should rewrite it)

if you have a return in a for loop it will return from the function the first time it reaches the return statement, leaving the loop behind

OK, I had a brain fart when writting this question... Actualy @diggusbickus you were right and I have a mess in main.py. What the problem was - identation of last line. The methods were both fine.... (facepal emoji)

So kids let me tell you a tale of a beginner developer (me) who is so focused on a single task that he forgot about the basics...
The answer lies in the indentation of the second main.py code, the last line :D
But if you have any comments on the code itself or the methods used, please do not have mercy!

Just delete the question, an answer like this serves no lasting benefit.
